# Segmentation fault when wrapping functions in valgrind

Tags: c, pthreads, valgrind

I'm trying to make a valgrind tool for measure some thread related things from `pthread.h` library. For doing this I need to wrap some functions.

The tool has 2 files: `fb_main.c` and `fb_intercept.c`.

`fb_intercept.c` is where the wrappers are. I began trying with a simple example wrapping `pthread_create` function.

`fb_intercept.c`:

```
#include "pub_tool_basics.h"
#include "pub_tool_redir.h"
#include "pub_tool_clreq.h"
#include "valgrind.h"
#include "config.h"

int I_WRAP_SONAME_FNNAME_ZZ(VG_Z_LIBPTHREAD_SONAME, pthreadZucreateZAZa)
    (pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start) (void*), void *arg)
{
    int result;
    OrigFn fn;
    VALGRIND_GET_ORIG_FN(fn);
    CALL_FN_W_WWWW(result, fn, thread, attr, start, arg);
    return result;
}
```

For some reason when I run a program with this tool I have the following error:

```
--5013-- VG_USERREQ__CLIENT_CALL2: func=0x0
==5013== 
==5013== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==5013==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x10
==5013==    at 0x35006084D1: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.18.so)
==5013==    by 0x4A07BF3: pthread_create@* (fb_intercept.c:66)
==5013==    by 0x40074E: main (in /home/andres/Documents/valgrind/prueba/a.out)
==5013==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==5013==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==5013==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==5013==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==5013==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
```

Actually the problem comes when I call `CALL_FN_W_WWWW(result, fn, thread, attr, start, arg)`. When I comment this line there are no errors, just `pthread_create` doesn't work properly as expected.

I thought this was supposed to work that way but it doesn't, and I don't know what that error means or what I'm missing. Possibly someone knows a little more about this kind of stuff.

I'm using valgind 3.11 from the svn repository.

Comment: Is that the actual code, or are you calling other functions inside the wrapper before `VALGRIND_GET_ORIG_FN()`? Things work here (Ubuntu 14.10, valgrind-3.10.0, amd64) with that example and `int I_WRAP_SONAME_FNNAME_ZZ(libpthreadZdsoZd0, pthreadZucreateZAZa)`, including if I add a `puts()` after `VALGRIND_GET_ORIG_FN()`.

Comment: @Ulfalizer: The wrapper function is just that, I'm not calling any other function before VALGRIND_GET_ORIG_FN(). I tryied with valgrind-3.10.0 and get the same. libpthreadZdsoZd0 is exactly the same that VG_Z_LIBPTHREAD_SONAME(there is macro where VG_Z_... is defined that way in valgrind.h). The only difference is that I'm working in Fedora 20. But it's strange because with what you said I don't know why helgrind is working with no problems.

Comment: @Ulfalizer : When you tried that example, did you handle user requests?

Comment: I just included your function verbatim (except for using `libpthreadZdsoZd0` instead of `VG_Z_LIBPTHREAD_SONAME`). I also confirmed that the wrapper (as well as the thread function) is called when running under Valgrind by adding some debug printouts. (If I use `VG_Z_LIBPTHREAD_SONAME` instead, I get e.g. these errors: `valgrind: m_demangle/demangle.c:231 (vgPlain_maybe_Z_demangle): the 'impossible' happened.`, `valgrind: symbol with a 'VG_Z_' prefix: _vgw00000ZZ_VG_Z_LIBPTHREAD_SONAME_pthreadZucreateZAZa.`.)

Comment: "Running under Valgrind" was just a plain `$ valgrind ./wrap`.

Comment: @Ulfalizer : hey I tried in ubuntu 14.04 and I can't make it work. I have this now: --21053-- VG_USERREQ__CLIENT_CALL2: func=0x0
               --21053-- VG_USERREQ__CLIENT_CALL1: func=0x0
               Unexpected error.                                                                                 Maybe is somthing related with user request. I don't know how did you do

Comment: Here's the program and output on my system: http://pastie.org/10037606#1

Comment: @Ulfalizer : I see... but it's not a valgrind tool. I was trying to make a tool like helgrind but minimal.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I've never done that. http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/writing-tools.html talks about needing to define certain functions (e.g. `pre_clo_init()`) and having them do various initialization. Have you done that?

Comment: @Ulfalizer : yes I did, actually I did a tool for measure some things related with memory usage similar to memcheck and I had no problems. Is just this about wrapping functions from pthread that is being difficult to me. Actually I have no problems when I try to wrap functions that are defined by me. That's why I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Not sure either then. Sorry. :/

Comment: @Ulfalizer Hey thanks a lot, I'll do it the you told me, you really helped me a lot.

Comment: @Ulfalizer : hey, did you test our example in C? In C worked fine for me but in C++ I can't wrapp the fuctions.

Comment: It's because C++ compilers mangle names differently (use a different name format in object files). It's so that C++ can support many overloaded functions with the same name. Valgrind expects C-style mangling. To fix it, you could add `extern "C"` before the declaration, like `extern "C" int I_WRAP_SONAME...`, to tell the compiler to do C mangling.